# detecting lying position with kinect

Tags: c#, kinect, kinect-sdk

I am trying to make a app in c# that will detect / classify 3 poses of human body which are standing, sitting and lying. I can correctly detect / classify 2 of them (sitting and standing) with skeleton tracking. When it comes to lying on the floor, Kinect seems to not be able to track skeleton of a human body.

Does anyone have any experiences with skeleton tracking in lying position? As soon as I lye down, I am loosing joints positions. Is this task impossible? Thank you.

Comment: I think this is a shortcoming in the technology, the kinect can't know the joints locations due to lack of visual info when the person is lying down.

Answer (score 0):

The Windows SDK for Kinect V1 is not great at recognizing people lying down.

V2 improves a lot on this, I would recommend you to participate in the beta or wait for V2.

One possible solution with V1, is to place a second camera vertically on the floor, use seated mode - so it detects on motion - and see if you find a person with that camera and not on the other, then it is likely lying down.
I have not tested this solution, but in theory it can work - try to set it up yourself and see if it fits your scenario needs.